# Is it a BAD design to have [DataContract] marked class in the business layer?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontract

I need to use a class that represents a Client Request that is sent to my REST WCF Service.

But I want to pass this request also to my method in the business layer. (Currently it is part of the WCF service)

Is it a BAD design to have [DataContract] marked class in the business layer?

Comment: There is no simple right or wrong. It depends on the complexity of your application.

Comment: If you feel bad about it introduce an interface that is implemented by that class and use that in your business layer. Note that `DataContract` attribute is merely marker for serialization engine.

Comment: @Rafal : I like the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I stated in comment:

If you feel bad about it introduce an interface that is implemented by that class and use that in your business layer. Note that DataContract attribute is merely marker for serialization engine.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be a useful answer.  Basically your POCO's can be serialized by `DataContractSerializer` without adding the `[DataContract]` attributes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14185417/1099260

Comment: +1 with one proviso. If the class isn't annotated with `DataContract`, and none of the members are decorated with `DataMember`, the `DataContractSerializer` is going to try to serialise _all_ of the members of the the class. This may not be desirable as it may surface data to the client that wasn't expected. Also, if you are using auto implemented properties, they may not serialize nicely. It's important to check what _actually_ gets serialized, and what it looks like.

Comment: @Nick: thanks, that is useful info.

Answer (score 0):

If the other option is to almost duplicate the contract to a different, "BL class", just to make you feel better about not sending DataContracts to a certain layer - I'd say don't - send the DataContract.

Also, "request", "command" and "data transfer object" are not strictly "facade" objects (or patterns). You can use a request object in your DAL API (I assume a layered architecture) in order to simplify method signatures and enable future refactorings, right? So why not use the same request object in all your layers?

If there are deployment issues (I can't think of any) with regards to the actual DataContract attribute - than it's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

If, in the future, you are going to need different interfaces of the REST WCF Client Request service and you don't have control over the consuming clients, you may have problems if your BL is heavily dependent on the WCF contract class. It might become difficult for you to modify the service interface without breaking your BL, or modify your BL without breaking the interface to your clients.

If neither of the above apply to you, I'd say go ahead with what @Rahal said in his comment (I've +1'd him).