# Why does WCF not raise an error when DataContract is missing?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, datacontract

The problem I have is that I'm new to WCF, and just in the process of rigging up some WCF `net.tcp` client-server communication.

The connection worked fine, but when the call goes through to the server, the passed parameter object has all fields set to `0`or `null`. This is especially fascinating as the type I'm passing <strike>*cannot even be constructed to have all fields zero*</strike>! (edit: actually, that *would* have been true if that type had been a `class`, but it is a struct, and `struct` in C# [*always* has a parameterless constructor](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#struct.constructors) that sets all field to zero. The rest of the problem stands as described.)

After investigation, it seems that I must specify a [`DataContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for my custom parameters on the service. I'm fine with that, <strike>I'll add it and it will hopefully work,</strike> I have added DataContract to `MyStruct` (only) and it now works, but I fail to get why:

- There is no compilation error
- There is no runtime error (from WCF - my code fires an assertion for the invalid field)
- WCF is apparently transferring a type and reconstructing objects without even using the c'tor of the objects. (and zero'ing out everything)

Why is that? Why is WCF transferring garbage without telling me? Is it a feature or a misfeature?

---

If it matters, here's a sketch of the types involved:

```
    ....
    [OperationContract]
    void Append(List<MyClassType> lines);

    ....
// Note: No DataContract here whatsoever
public class MyClassType
{
    private List<MyStruct> _values = new List<MyStruct>();

    public IList<MyStruct> Values
    {
        get { return _values; }
    }
....
// Note: No DataContract here whatsoever
public struct MyStruct
{
    readonly int m_tag;
    readonly float m_data;

    public MyStruct(float data)
    {
        m_tag = 1; // m_tag is *never* 0
        m_data = data;
....
```

On the server side, I receive a list of `MyClassType` with the `Values` list set to the correct number of `MyStruct` instances, but all the `MyStruct` object are zero'd out, even though regularly it is not even possible to construct such an object with `m_tag` set to zero!

---

**Digging deeper** (update): Answers so far have been helpful, but fail to address the *why* of my specific example, and also fail to address that it doesn't seem to make too much sense to transfer `MyStruct` - it doesn't even have a parameterless constructor! Specifically, I found [*Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx), which states:

> The DataContractSerializer ... supports many other types, which can be thought of
>   as having an implicit data contract. The following is a complete list
>   of types that can be serialized:

- All publicly visible types that have a constructor that does not have parameters.
- ...

`MyStruct` (below) clearly does *not* have a parameterless constructor, and still it is transferred and "reconstructed" using zero bytes. **This seems to contradict the MSDN article.** (Unless "not supported" means: "We'll silently transfer garbage without telling you.")

---

- VS 2010 / .NET 4.0 for the WCF client and service
- MyClassType + MyStruct are defined in an assembly that is set to target .NET 3.0 Thought this might be relevant: ["*WCF will serialize Plain Old Class Objects correctly as long as you are on .Net 3.5 SP1 or later.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14185417/321013)

Comment: if you don't add DataContract then serializer assume that you dont want to serialize that class and same with datamember

Comment: @pramod - dunno what *it* assumes. *I'd* assumed that if it doesnt/cant handle a type, it would raise an error instead of silently transmitting garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class has no serialization attributes recognised by WCF, then WCF will treat the class as if it was a `DataContract` with all public fields and properties as `DataMember`s. This behaviour was added in version 3.5, and since you are on version 4.0, you will see that behaviour. The version that your class was created with is not important, it's the WCF host that controls the behaviour.

You see `m_tag = 0` because the `DataContractSerializer` does not call any of your class constructors. It constructs a blank object using [GetUninitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then it sets all field values from the deserialised data stream. If the `m_tag` element in the message contains `0`, then the field will end up with that value. It will also be zero if the `m_tag` element is missing from the message, since WCF data contract members are optional by default.

The best way to avoid problems like this is to regard all your data contracts as dumb data transfer objects, with no behaviour at all. Any field validation should be done inside the service operation (which is good security practice anyway). However, if you *really* want to bake this validation into the data contract class, then you can do so with [OnDeserializingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx).

Comment: What would actually suit me best were if WCF would immediately error out when it encounters a type of mine that does not define a Datacontract.  Do you know whether there is a policy for this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you don't want WCF to treat a class as a data contract, then don't reference it in a service contract or fault contract. It's just a matter of coding discipline. Only use classes that have been designed to be data contracts and are marked as such, then you will get predictable behaviour and no nasty surprises.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of incorrect assumptions.

Your first assumption is that WCF should treat all objects as serializable.  This is a false assumption, since often times objects have runtime members or calculated members, or even non-serializable members (Bitmaps, for instance, because they contain display hardware specific device contexts that are meaningless on a different computer).

DataContracts are explicit (with a few exceptions) and you must define which members you want serialized.  There is no error generated if you don't include members, because this is a valid situation, and happens a lot more often than you might assume.

Your second assumption is that WCF uses constructors to rebuild your objects.  It doesn't.  It creates objects at a low level, otherwise it would be unable to serialize objects with private properties or fields, and you would be forced to make objects public, or create constructors that you don't need in order to serialize them.

Your third assumption is that WCF can know that you intend to do specific things when you haven't told it so.  WCF is not magic, and it can't read minds.  It can only work within the parameters of what it knows.  If you don't tell it you want to transfer something, it won't do it (again, with certain exceptions defined by convention).

Comment: Actually, I only had the assumption that if WCF doe not know how to serialize something, it would tell me so, at least at runtime. Why is silently transferring garbage valuable, especially in light of "DataContracts are explicit". Whats the use case of transferring types that WCF knows are neither marked as Serializable nor as DataContract???